# Why my AJAX Request to Codeigniter 4.21 response OK, but won't bind to select2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, jquery-select2

**I'm trying to implement AJAX Request to Codeigniter 4.21 route and bind it to select2, the result data was OK, but won't binded to select2. Is there any solution?**

**Controller**

```
public function getSpesialis(){

  
        $response = array();
  
        
        $userlist = $this->spesialisModel->findAll();
        
  
        $data = array();

        foreach($userlist as $user){
           $data[] = array(
              "id" => $user['id'],
              "spesialis" => $user['spesialis'],
           );
        }
  
        $response['data'] = $data;
  
        return $this->response->setJSON($response);
  
     }
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
    $('#spesialis').select2({
        placeholder: "Pilih Spesialisasi...",
        ajax: {
            url: '/getspesialis',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            delay: 250,
            processResults: function(data) {
                return {
                    results: data
                    
                };
            }

        },

    });
```

Comment: Welcome! Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Answer (score 0):

it's DONE with this... thanks all

```
$('#spesialis').select2({
    placeholder: "Pilih Spesialisasi...",
    ajax: {
        url: '/getspesialis',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        delay: 250,
        processResults: function({
            data
        }) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        id: item.id,
                        text: item.spesialis
                    }
                })
            }
        }

    },

});
```